# Not submitting data into database

Tags: php, mysql

What should be a simple code isn't working out for me. It's displaying the HTML Woo! message but it's not actually submitting data.

```
$forgetKeyEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']);
$resetUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputUser']);
if ($_GET['do'] == "update") 
{
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(10, false);
    $resetPassword = $hasher->HashPassword(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPassword']));
    if ($_POST['inputPassword'] !== "")
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$resetPassword' WHERE forgetKey = '$forgetKeyEmail'");
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin:0;">
            <strong>Woooo!</strong> Your password has been changed, you can now <a href="login.php">login.</a>
            </div>
            <?php
    }
    else 
    {
             ?>
            <div class="alert alert-error" style="margin:0;">
            <strong>Woops!</strong> You need to fill out a password!
            </div>
            <?php
    }
}
```

Here is the form HTML for refernce:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="?do=update" >
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">New Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: echo the query, does it look right? add mysql_error()

Comment: Agree with previous comments and also check out the errorcode that your query might return

Comment: Have you checked to see if $forgetKeyEmail is what you expect?

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` functionality in PHP. It is deprecated and dangerous. You should use PDO objects, or mysqli. [Here is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for prepared statements with PDO objects.

Comment: @murph: Change your code as:
`$result=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$resetPassword' WHERE forgetKey = '$forgetKeyEmail'");`
`if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Run it and paste here the error msg.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw it just says "Invalid Query:" - nothing else.

Comment: @murph: I am quite shocked. Ok, Do the following: this will surely confirm what's the error. `echo $result;` .Whatever is printed, copy and open phpmyadmin. Select the database and paste the query in SQL box. Run it.If there is any error, mysql will display.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw disregard my last comment. That was incorrect. I am getting a result of "1" (while echoing $result outside of your if statement) however no change in the database. Which doesn't make sense, as further on in the script it updates a field perfectly.

Comment: @murph: I am quite sorry, there was a small mistake in my second last comment:

`$sql="UPDATE users SET password = '$resetPassword' WHERE forgetKey = '$forgetKeyEmail'";` `echo $sql;` Add these two statements before  `mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ...` Whatever is printed, copy and open phpmyadmin. Select the database and paste the query in SQL box. Run it.If there is any error, mysql will display.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw that helped me. Turns out that it couldn't grab the 'key' value as when you submit the form there is no 'key' in the url. So I just changed the form action to:
`?do=update&key=<?php echo $forgetKeyEmail; ?>`

However, is there any other way for me to achieve this?

Comment: @murph:I had converted it to answer, so that it can help others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a small mistake in following  line:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="?do=update" >
```

Whenever form is submitted, the url  is  `..?do=update`.

Since, we are collecting(grabbing) **key** value as a **GET** variable:

```
$forgetKeyEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']);
```

Therefore, `$forgetKeyEmail` is an empty string as there is no **key** in the url, that is `$_GET['key']` is unset.

Hence change the above html code to:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action=?do=update&key=<?php echo $forgetKeyEmail; ?>
```

It will work like a Charm.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, it's something as silly as case sensitivity or misspelled form name.  Doublecheck the case on your table and field names, the querystring values, etc.